# specifying a different lcoation for the templates folder(flask)

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

im trying to rearrange my project into a more logical structure like below. however I cant seem to get the create_app function to recognise the new location of the templates and statics folder.
I've tried using  `app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False,  template_folder='Frontend/')` but its throwing the 'template not found error' any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
plp
-backend
-Frontend
 --templates
 --static
-utils
-config
-startup
 --__init__.py(where the Create_app function is)
```

Comment: as a starter `frontend` vs `Frontend`

Comment: yes that's mistake on here but not on the code. apologies

Comment: In order to have a valid Python package, you should have a `__init__.py` at the top level directory. Afaik, this is usually also the place where to put the `create_app` function.

Comment: I never felt the need to choose a custom template folder, so I am not 100% sure, but I think you need to set the path incl. the `templates` directory, so at least it would be `frontend/templates`.

Comment: adding a empty __init__.py file to the root seems to have fixed the issue. thank you